# Defining variable using eval() shows undefined error

Tags: javascript, variables, eval, undefined

When defining variable directly, it works. Like the following code, the background color of body will be light green in IE and will be light blue in non-IE browsers.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        if (window.attachEvent) {
            var YourBrowserIsIE = true;
        }

        if (YourBrowserIsIE) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, sometimes the variable need to be defined using eval(), like the following, but the result will show an error saying that `YourBrowserIsIE` is undefined in non-IE browsers.

```
if (window.attachEvent) {
    eval('var YourBrowserIsIE = true;');
}
```

Yes, I know I can predefine `var YourBrowserIsIE = false;` for non-IE browsers or change the if statement to `if (typeof YourBrowserIsIE != 'undefined')`, but I want to keep the code as minimum as possible.

So is there a solution to use eval() to define the variable and check the variable using the straightforward `if (YourBrowserIsIE)` without showing any error in non-IE browsers?

**== EDIT ==**

Sorry for being unclear. The situation of using eval() being mentioned above is actually for detecting IE version. Please see the following code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        if (window.attachEvent) {
            var version = /msie (\d+)/i.exec(navigator.userAgent)[1];
            eval('var YourBrowserIsIE' + version + ' = true;');
        }

        if (YourBrowserIsIE9) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `YourBrowserIsIE` be undefined in non-IE browser in both your codes? As long as `window.attachEvent` does not exist, `YourBrowserIsIE` will never be defined.

Comment: What about `var attachEvent` in global scope? My browser isn't necessarily IE, but your code will treat it as such.

Comment: Why do you think you need `eval` for this?

Comment: Thanks all and sorry for being unclear. I had edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried `window['YourBrowserIsIE' + version] = true;`

Comment: @some, thanks and tried, but had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I want to keep the code as minimum as possible

Wouldn't that be `window.YourBrowserIsIE = window.attachEvent;` then?

I see 2 advantages it it:

1. It's minimal
2. It doesn't need `eval`

Seeing your code, i'd suggest to not use `YourBrowserIsIE` at all, but use:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = window.attachEvent 
                                       ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightblue';
```

And seeing your edits, that could/would be:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 
              +((/msie (\d+)/i.exec(navigator.userAgent)||[0])[1]) === 9 
                ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightblue';
```

And if it has to be a reusable variable, I come back to solution 1 whith a twitch:

```
window['YourBrowserIsIE'+((/msie (\d+)/i.exec(navigator.userAgent)||[0])[1]] 
       = true;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = window.YourBrowserIsIE9 ?
                                       ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightblue';
```

Comment: `window.YourBrowserIsIE = !!window.attachEvent;` to make it a boolean.

Comment: Thanks. However, the variable YourBrowserIsIE9 might be reused many times.

Comment: Code will throw error in non-IE browsers, since [1] cannot be read of null.

Comment: @Sandreep: look closer `(/msie (\d+)/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) /*==>*/ || [0])[1]`

Comment: Okay, it seems that the closest way is testing window.YourBrowserIsIE9 like @Kooilnc said.

Answer (score 1):

Put an `else` case to your `if` condition and try:

```
if (window.attachEvent) {
    eval('var YourBrowserIsIE = true;');
}
else{
    eval('var YourBrowserIsIE = false;');
}
```

Since you are declaring the variable `YourBrowserIsIE` inside the  `if (window.attachEvent)` condition, the variable will be left undefined if the mentioned condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested there is no need to perform eval.

Anyways, if you are looking to set the code to true/false; you can perform this

```
eval('var YourBrowserIsIE = window.attachEvent ? true : false;')
```

Unless you share the actual problem, it will be difficult to provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that using object inference is a seriously flawed way to detect the user agent (lots of browsers copy IE's event model) and is therefore extremely unreliable, here's how you might do what you are trying to do without eval and with minimal code:

[... ugh, see Kooilnc's answer ...]